# 3D waving flag in Android (using cloth simulation)

Tags: android, opengl-es, simulation

My goal is to create a **waving flag in Android** using **OpenGL** but I don't have any clue on where to start.

Cloth modeling seems to make the neatest effect but I couldn't find any implementation for Android on the web.

I hope that someone would know some tutorials, resources etc. that could help me solve this problem.

If you know easier/other ways to create a decent looking waving flag, let me know. I'm open for everything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The hard way: http://insanitydesign.com/wp/projects/nehe-android-ports/ & http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=cloth+animation or just prerender the flag and display a series of images

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will try to use Android NDK and OpenGL and port some C code. If I get it to work, I'll post the results here.

Comment: @HD_92 I am working on a similar dilemma. Please did you find a good solution?  Would you like to share? Thanks, maurizio

Answer (score 2):

First result on google
http://code.google.com/p/waving-flag-android/

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about that. It doesn't look that bad but is somewhat limited. I was looking for something more fancy with wind, gravity and shadows (like cloth simulation).

Answer (score 1):

A good tutorial about cloth simulation is from Jesper Mosegaard http://cg.alexandra.dk/2009/06/02/mosegaards-cloth-simulation-coding-tutorial/

The pioneer work on cloth simulation is from Darwin 3D http://www.darwin3d.com/gdm1999.htm#gdm0599

A open source project in Google Code provides a variety of algorithms http://code.google.com/p/opencloth/

All these works are based on C/C++ which is the natural programming language for OpenGL. As you are working on an Android project, you have to rewrite the algorithms in Java. After you figure out the mechanism, you should be fine. Good luck!